# Can L'Hospital's rule be applied to a limit of the form of (inf * inf)/inf?

Tags: limits, analysis

My teacher wanted us to resolve this limit using L'Hospital. 
$\lim_{x\to +∞}  \frac{(e^x)(x-1)}{x^2}$

But I can't understand why she derived the numerator, as it's an indefinite form (inf * inf) and I don't understand why L'Hospital's rule can be directly applied. Thank you in advance

Comment: Sure because \infty*\infty=\infty and you must verify the conditions of de l’Hopital hypothesis

Comment: The denominator is $x\cdot x$, and is therefore also of the form $\infty\cdot\infty$, yet that doesn't seem to bother you. Why not?

Comment: It is in the form $\frac {\infty} {\infty}$ and L'Hopital Rule is applicable.

Comment: It is not very well-known that L'Hospital's Rule applies to the form "$\text{anything} /\infty $" and hence it is applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the numerator as $xe^x-e^x$, then the expression at the limit is of the form $\infty/\infty$ and L'hopital's rule applies.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we have no any problems: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{(x-1)e^x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{(x-1)e^x+e^x}{2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{xe^x+e^x}{2}=+\infty.$$